# How to install Prophet in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, facebook-prophet

In Apache Spark 3.3.0 I want to install Prophet to use it with pyspark.

```
$ pyspark --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.13.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_332
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ubuntu on 2022-06-09T18:15:33Z
Revision f74867bddfbcdd4d08076db36851e88b15e66556
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
```

and I have

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

I'm very new in python, I have tried:

1)

```
>>> from fbprophet import Prophet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet'
>>> pip install Prophet
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install Prophet
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

2. 

```
>>> from prophet import Prophet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'
>>>
```

3. 

```
$ pip install prophet
-bash: pip: command not found
```

So here the question is how to install [prophet](https://pypi.org/project/prophet/) in Apache Spark to use with pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run
`pip install prophet`
in your terminal (outside Apache Spark), not your Python script.

Once prophet is installed you can refer to it in your Python code.
Use:

```
from prophet import Prophet
```

fbprophet is the old name of the package, unless you want to use the old release, use prophet instead.

Comment: I tried "$ pip install prophet -bash: pip: command not found". But in that case the libraries would be installed for python 2.7.8 not for pyspark, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have python installed locally? Pyspark is just another python library, just like prophet